# django sitemap has no style information

Tags: python, django

I have setup a django sitemap using the sitemap framework built into django.

However although the content of the sitemap looks fine it doesn't generate the typical style / format information normally for a sitemap. And when reviewing in the browser I see the error:

`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

Apart from this error the sitemap displays correctly:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://www.myexample.com/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.myexample.com/about/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
....
```

my sitemap file sitemaps.py is:

```py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse


class HomeSitemap(Sitemap):
    """Reverse static views for XML sitemap"""
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 1.0

    def items(self):
        return ['home', ]

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)


class StaticSitemap(Sitemap):
    """Reverse static views for XML sitemap"""
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return ['about', 'faq', 'contact', 'terms', 'privacy', 'signup']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

urls.py relevant section

```py
...
sitemaps = {'home': HomeSitemap, 'static': StaticSitemap}
...
url(r'^sitemap\.xml/$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='signup'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is standard in the browser to have the message regarding missing styling and although the encoding is not visible it can be viewed in the request response in the dev tools, where you can see the full xml file incloding encoding details, ie

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`